# Getting 500 Error while generating WSDL in Soap Webservices in java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am getting below while creating web services in java.I am using jdk 1.8.Same application is working in another system.

But Client Side-Java Proxy is working properly..

**HTTP ERROR: 500**
Problem accessing /wse/perspective_toolbar.jsp;jsessionid=4wcj5ao8uenq7piua5t4m1vc. Reason:

```
PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
```

PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 19 in the jsp file: /perspective_toolbar.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

---

### Powered by Jetty://

Thanks,

Parveen.

I have solve the above problem by uninstalling jdk8 and installing jdk7.It seems I got this issue because of jdk8.

Thanks,

Parveen.

Comment: There is a server code error that result 500 error code. You can check the error logs for more details.

Comment: some details of this error is given in http://sourceforge.net/p/drjava/bugs/944/